# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' cannot be translated into a store expression C# asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I try to order Departments by number, but since the departement number stored as a string in database, I can't just use Order by number. 
I try to parse it as float but it did not work. Then I tried to parse it as Double. That does not work either. Any suggestions? The following is my code.

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var datasource = (from x in db.Departments 
                      orderby double.Parse(x.DepartmentNumber) 
                      select x).ToList();
    lvData.DataSource = datasource;
    lvData.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks for the answer, I did the following, but the results are not entirly correct.

```
 var datasource = (from x in db.Departments orderby x.DepartmentNumber select x).ToList().OrderBy(Department => float.Parse(Department.DepartmentNumber));
```

[image]

Comment: I'm bit supreised that `DepartmentNmber` is not type of duoble.

Comment: We can't guess what your definition of "correct" is. Do you mean you want `209.01` to appear before `222`? The sorting shown in the screenshot would seem to suggest your locale uses a comma as decimal point, then parse for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just figured it out and it works now. Please read my answer further down.

Comment: Yeah see the linked duplicates. It helps to break up a problem in smaller parts, then you'll find each of them has been asked and answered before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the following solved the problem and provided the required results:

```
 var datasource = (from x in db.Departments orderby x.DepartmentNumber select x).ToList().OrderBy(Department => Convert.ToDouble(Department.DepartmentNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One solution it would be the following:

```
var datasource = db.Departments 
                   .ToList()
                   .OrderBy(department => double.Parse(department.DepartmentNumber));
```

You fetch all the data from the database in the memory of your application (by calling `ToList`, which requests the immediate execution of the query.) and then you make the ordering in memory.

The reason why the query below doesn't work:

```
var datasource = (from x in db.Departments 
                  orderby double.Parse(x.DepartmentNumber) 
                  select x).ToList();
```

is the fact that `double.Parse` *cannot* be translated to an equivalent function in sql and then the whole sql query be submitted to the database for execution.

Comment: In a Short: the magic is in `.ToList()` method before `OrderBy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer please read my edit in the original question

Comment: @Mindan You are welcome. I saw your edit and as it seems you didn't follow the approach I proposed above. Could you please make a try and let me known ? Thanks

Comment: @Mindan You mean the suggested approach. Correct?